# Springer journal template issue in XeLatex Compiler Overleaf

Tags: xetex, overleaf, springer

While using the following springer journal template in Overleaf : [Link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/springer-nature-latex-template/myxmhdsbzkyd) , If I select XeLatex as compiler immediately it shows 38 errors and the bibliography disappears. But everything is ok if I use it using Pdflatex compiler. How to run this template using XeLatex compiler without any error and without vanishing bibliography. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle showing 38 errors is not practical here. I have added the link of that particular template so that anyone who really wants to help can recreate this problem in their Overleaf account.

Comment: only the first error matters.

Comment: You assume everyone has an overleaf account.

Comment: I don't debug projects given through an overleaf account. Such questions will useless ones the link expire. You should make a complete example here, and also show the error message.

Answer (score 1):

the file says

```
%% to compile with pdflatex/xelatex use pdflatex option %%
```

and if I change

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style
```

to

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered,pdflatex]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style
```

it runs without error